# application Installation problem

Tags: android

I am novice in android development.

my application is not installing in emulator.
i saw this in logcat
**failed to load properties file for project android**
what is this please help me

thanks in advance
Arindom ghosh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse (which you should, being a novice), try right-clicking the project in the package explorer and choose **Android Tools ➙ Fix Project Properties** and maybe **Project ➙ Clean...** in the window menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Computer (or my computer) sorry I'm not english so don't know what exactly that in English version. Then choose special. Then System Variables. Here choose Edit.
Here write your jdk's path. After this write a semicolon and write your avd's file path. Semicolon and OK.

Try it. If it isn't good try reinstall your ADT. But I think the first will solve your problem.